# Как можно укоротить решение уравнений через sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

Я хотел бы сделать свой код приятнее по возможности. Как можно изменить код, чтобы не писать кучу таких условий? Функция принимает коэффициенты, знак и ответ. Уравнения имеют вид: k +/*- x = answer

```
def solve_type_5(K1, char4, A):
    if char4 == '-':
        return solveset(Eq(int(K1) - x, int(A)), x)
    elif char4 == '+':
        return solveset(Eq(int(K1) + x, int(A)), x)
    elif char4 == '/':
        return solveset(Eq(int(K1) / x, int(A)), x)
    else:
        return solveset(Eq(int(K1) * x, int(A)), x)
```

Comment: вы хотя бы текстом привели код. Но если в нем нет проблем, то это скорее в гольф

Comment: Откуда взялся `x`?

Comment: это Symbol, типо искомая переменная

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, хотя приходится гадать, сработает ли в вашем случае - вы не дали полноценного примера кода, который можно было бы запустить и проверить:

```
from operator import add, sub, truediv, mul

def solve_type_5(K1, op, A):
    return solveset(Eq(op(int(K1), x), int(A)), x)

res = solve_type_5(K1, mul, A)
```

Ну либо если нужно именно из символов преобразовывать, то можно сделать словарь и преобразовывать символы в операции через него:

```
ch2op = {
    '-': sub,
    '+': add,
    '/': truediv,
    '*': mul
}
op = ch2op['-']
res = solve_type_5(1, op, 2)
```